How to get Unique columns in a Row and make the Formula "SPILL" and work for the other Rows as well?
I want to Turn (Unique) Function into a Formula that works like this ...
=N25:N29+O25:O29+P25:P29+Q25:Q29+R25:R29


This was an example of summing a few values in a formula that does that for 5 rows at the same time separately. (it Spills down to the other rows)
I can do the simple version of (unique) function that works for a single row like this ...
=UNIQUE(N38:R38,TRUE,TRUE)


i can (copy/paste) the function for other rows but i dont want it like that , i want a formula that does it for multiple rows at the same time separately like the summing i did in the first example.(i want it to spill down to the other rows)
do anyone know how to do that ?
I tried it like this but it didnt work ...
=UNIQUE(N32:N36&O32:O36&P32:P36&Q32:Q36&R32:R36,TRUE,TRUE)



Do you mean something along these lines perhaps:

Formula in H3:
=IFNA(DROP(LET(α,B3:F7,REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α)),LAMBDA(β,γ,VSTACK(β,IFERROR(UNIQUE(TOROW(INDEX(α,γ,0),1),1,1),""))))),1),"")
Note: You have now removed values that appeared more than once in the orginal rows as per your own attempt with UNIQUE(arr,1,1).

The same would be possible using MAKEARRAY:
=LET(range,A2:E6,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(range),COLUMNS(range),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(i,INDEX(range,r,), IFERROR(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(i,i<>""),1,1),c),"")))))

Where we first declare the range and create an array the same size.
Next with i we loop through the range row-wise.
We filter the row's values to remove blanks and apply the UNIQUE formula you had in mind. We index the result to return a single value from the calculated unique values (position c).
If the position is out of reference of the calculated array, it would return a #REF-error. We turn these into blanks using IFERROR.

Here is another alternative using REDUCE() functions:


• Formula used in cell H2
=LET(
     α, B3:F7,
     δ, IFNA(REDUCE(B2:F2,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(α)),LAMBDA(r,c,
     VSTACK(r,UNIQUE(CHOOSEROWS(α,c),1,1)))),""),
     IF(δ=0,"",δ))


One can also use INDEX() in place of CHOOSEROWS()
=LET(
     α, B3:F7,
     δ, IFNA(REDUCE(B2:F2,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(α)),LAMBDA(r,c,
        VSTACK(r,UNIQUE(INDEX(α,c,),1,1)))),""),
     IF(δ=0,"",δ))



Same main logic as JvdV's and Mayukh's, a bit verbose:
=LAMBDA(data,
    LET(
        num_cols, COLUMNS(data),
        once_only, LAMBDA(values,
            LET(
                values_wo_blanks, TOROW(values, 1),
                IFERROR(UNIQUE(values_wo_blanks, TRUE, TRUE), "")
            )
        ),
        REDUCE(
            CHOOSEROWS(data, 1),
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
            LAMBDA(acc_rows, cur_row,
                IF(
                    cur_row = 1,
                    acc_rows,
                    VSTACK(
                        acc_rows,
                        EXPAND(
                            once_only(CHOOSEROWS(data, cur_row)),
                            ,
                            num_cols,
                            ""
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)(B2:F7)

